# How can I do an AJAX call without using JSON?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I am trying to improve my jQuery and AJAX knowledge and I wanted to create a simple call to my database. However, I am having some issues with it and I can't really understand why. Here is the code:

```
function provaajax() {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'visualizza.php',           
        data: "",                      
        dataType: 'text',               
        complete: function(data) {
            var nome = data[0];
            var cognome = data[1];
            $('.provajax').html("<b>nome: </b>" + nome + "<b> cognome: </b>" + cognome);
        }
    });
}
```

And here is my PHP file:

```
<?
    Connection();
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM prova WHERE ID = 117");
    $array = mysql_result($result, 0, "Nome");
    $array = mysql_result($result, 0, "Cognome");
    echo $array;
?>
```

And a little code from my HTML:

```
<div>
    <button onclick="provaajax()">Prova Ajax</button>
    <p class="provajax"> Hello world </p>
</div>
```

But this code isn't working. I don't know how to use JSON, so it would be better not to use it. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To retrieve the `nome` and `cognome` values from your PHP it would probably be easiest to return JSON. To do that you can create an array with those values and encode it with `json_encode`:

```
<?
    Connection();
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM prova WHERE ID = 117");
    $arr = array('nome' => mysql_result($result, 0, "Nome"), 'cognome' => mysql_result($result, 0, "Cognome"));
    echo json_encode($arr);
?>
```

Then you can retrieve these values from the deserialised object provided to the `success` function by jQuery:

```
complete: function(data) {
    var nome = data.nome;
    var cognome = data.cognome;
    $('.provajax').html("<b>nome: </b>" + nome + "<b> cognome: </b>" + cognome);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked! But i needed to change data-type from "text" to "json"

Comment: You're right, I missed that, apologies. You could also leave out the `dataType` property if you require and let jQuery determine the response type itself if you prefer.